# How Do I bolden the $0 Value on the Y Axis that ways its easy to identify when slicing the data?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, linegraph, yaxis

How Do I bolden the $0 Value on the Y Axis that ways its easy to identify when slicing the data?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMGON.png)

I've tried google, tried looking through every setting. Not sure if this an available setting.

Answer (score 1):

use [Y-Axis Constant Line] under [further analysis] page. then set value as 0. details as screenshot below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkkEa.png)